# How get element value if name exist symbol "-"?

Tags: jq

In one of my projects exist json file

```json
{
  "name": "view1",
  "version": "1.1.1",
  "target-dir": "/opt/project/spark-jobs/",
  "target-hosts": {
    "dev": ["host1", "host2"],
    "prod": ["host3", "host4"]
  }
}
```

I have to read element of json "target-hosts",
for solve try to use JQ, but if try run command

```
jq '.target-hosts' deploy.json  
jq: error: dir/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.target-hosts        
jq: 1 compile error
```

How escape character "-"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
."target-hosts"
```

or

```
.["target-hosts"]
```

So,

```sh
jq '."target-hosts"' deploy.json
```

or

```sh
jq '.["target-hosts"]' deploy.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to quote the key name such as

```
jq '."target-hosts"' deploy.json
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/PnpLP-SC7Jv)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose in double quotes:

```
jq '."target-hosts"'
```